# Determine if a number falls within a specified set of ranges

Tags: c#, range

I'm looking for a fluent way of determining if a number falls within a specified set of ranges. My current code looks something like this:

```
int x = 500; // Could be any number

if ( ( x > 4199 && x < 6800 ) ||
     ( x > 6999 && x < 8200 ) ||
     ( x > 9999 && x < 10100 ) ||
     ( x > 10999 && x < 11100 ) ||
     ( x > 11999 && x < 12100 ) )
{
    // More awesome code
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Better in what sense?   This seems pretty reasonable

Comment: @Michael: I believe Steve is asking for a more eloquent approach.

Comment: I think the example you've provided is the best (looking and understandable) way to be honest!

Comment: I agree with ThePower.  Unless you have a huge list of numbers, and maybe even then, I think the way you have it is easy to read and understand. KISS.  Anton's first suggestion would be a close second.

Comment: I like this code, just drop the parenthesis around each && statement -- no need to clutter.

Comment: It is all about the "// More awesome code"

Comment: To get closer to the common way of writing 'x between 0 and 10' **( 0 < x < 10)** I'll use
    `if ( 0 < x && x < 10)`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Extension methods?

```
bool Between(this int value, int left, int right)
{ 
   return value > left && value < right; 
}

if(x.Between(4199, 6800) || x.Between(6999, 8200) || ...)
```

You can also do this awful hack:

```
bool Between(this int value, params int[] values)
{
    // Should be even number of items
    Debug.Assert(values.Length % 2 == 0); 

    for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i += 2)
        if(!value.Between(values[i], values[i + 1])
            return false;

    return true;
}

if(x.Between(4199, 6800, 6999, 8200, ...)
```

Awful hack, improved:

```
class Range
{
    int Left { get; set; }
    int Right { get; set; }

    // Constructors, etc.
}

Range R(int left, int right)
{
    return new Range(left, right)
}

bool Between(this int value, params Range[] ranges)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; ++i)
        if(value > ranges[i].Left && value < ranges[i].Right)
            return true;

    return false;
}

if(x.Between(R(4199, 6800), R(6999, 8200), ...))
```

Or, better yet (this does not allow duplicate lower bounds):

```
bool Between(this int value, Dictionary<int, int> ranges)
{
    // Basically iterate over Key-Value pairs and check if value falls within that range
}

if(x.Between({ { 4199, 6800 }, { 6999, 8200 }, ... }
```

Comment: I would *definitely* make Range immutable. Mutability sucks for things like this...

Comment: Whoa! _Formatting_ in **comments**!

@Jon Yes, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 14):

Define a Range type, then create a set of ranges and an extension method to see whether a value lies in any of the ranges. Then instead of hard-coding the values, you can create a collection of ranges and perhaps some individual ranges, giving them useful names to explain *why* you're interested in them:

```
static readonly Range InvalidUser = new Range(100, 200);
static readonly Range MilkTooHot = new Range (300, 400);

static readonly IEnumerable<Range> Errors =
    new List<Range> { InvalidUser, MilkTooHot };

...

// Normal LINQ (where Range defines a Contains method)
if (Errors.Any(range => range.Contains(statusCode))
// or (extension method on int)
if (statusCode.InAny(Errors))
// or (extension methods on IEnumerable<Range>)
if (Errors.Any(statusCode))
```

You may be interested in the generic `Range` type which is part of [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil). It allows for iteration in a simple way as well:

```
foreach (DateTime date in 19.June(1976).To(25.December(2005)).Step(1.Days()))
{
    // etc
}
```

(Obviously that's also using some DateTime/TimeSpan-related extension methods, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 8):

I personally prefer the extension method suggested by @Anton - but if you can't do that, and are going to stick with your current code, I think you could make it more readable by reversing the first set of conditions on each line as follows...

```
int x = 500; // Could be any number
if ( ( 4199 < x && x < 6800 ) ||
     ( 6999 < x && x < 8200 ) ||
     ( 9999 < x && x < 10100 ) ||
     ( 10999 < x && x < 11100 ) ||
     ( 11999 < x && x < 12100 ) )
{
    // More awesome code
}
```

Comment: This makes it a lot more readable. It's pointed out in Code Complete and I've been using this style ever since.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ approach :

Add the reference:

```
using System.Linq;

        /// <summary>
        /// Test to see if value is in specified range.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aStart">int</param>
        /// <param name="aEnd">int</param>
        /// <param name="aValueToTest">int</param>
        /// <returns>bool</returns>
        public static bool CheckValueInRange(int aStart, int aEnd, int aValueToTest)
        {
            // check value in range...
            bool ValueInRange = Enumerable.Range(aStart, aEnd).Contains(aValueToTest);
            // return value...
            return ValueInRange;
        }
```

Comment: CheckValueInRange only works at the lower bound of the range.  Since the second parameter of Enumerable.Range is the number of values to add to the sequence (instead of the end of the range), values higher than the upper bound would still be reported as in range. Example: CheckValueInRange(4199,6800,6801) would return True, despite 6801 being outside the desired upper bound because Enumerable.Range(4199,6800) returns a range of numbers from 4199 to 10998.

Comment: This approach is very bad for performance, because array will be allocated with length of range and LINQ will try to iterate it to find your test value.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Range { 

    public Range(int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

var ranges = new List<Range>();
ranges.Add(new Range(4199,6800));
ranges.Add(new Range(6999,8200));
ranges.Add(new Range(9999,10100));
ranges.Add(new Range(10999,11100));
ranges.Add(new Range(11999,12100));

bool inRange = ranges.Count(r => x >= r.X && x <= r.Y) > 0;
//or -- Based on Jons recommendation
bool inRange = ranges.Any(r => x >= r.X && x <= r.Y);
```

Comment: It's generally better to use Any() than Count(...) > 0 as then it can stop as soon as it's found a match.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add that to the post.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to iterate over the value pairs at some point, I suggest you capture the maximum lower value and the minimum upper value as you do into variables and do:

```
if ( x>max_lower && x <min_upper)
{
    // More awesome code

}
```

Comment: what if that is not impossible?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, said _what if that is not impossible?_, not impossible= possible? I'm not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
struct Range
{
   public readonly int LowerBound;
   public readonly int UpperBound; 

   public Range( int lower, int upper )
   { LowerBound = lower; UpperBound = upper; }

   public bool IsBetween( int value )
   { return value >= LowerBound && value <= UpperBound; }
}

public void YourMethod( int someValue )
{
   List<Range> ranges = {new Range(4199,6800),new Range(6999,8200),
                         new Range(9999,10100),new Range(10999,11100),
                         new Range(11999,12100)};

   if( ranges.Any( x => x.IsBetween( someValue ) )
   {
      // your awesome code...
   }
}
```